# How to answer "what are you bad at?"

Tags: sentence-structure, responses

In a team, we have been asked the question "what are you bad at?" and how can we answer it in a positive way?

The answer I given was "being stucked with the work which I want to achieve"

I'm thinking that I would have answered it in a better way.

Answer (score 1):

As for the question itself, I'm guessing it is trying to identify areas for improvement, not what you don't like about your current situation. Given that...

> being stucked with the work which I want to achieve

won't work, because "stuck" has a negative implication here, while "I want to achieve" is a positive one. Also, "stucked" is not grammatical.

For example:

> I got stuck with cleaning the kitchen.

means having to do something you really don't want to.

So for your answer, how about these:

> I'm not **good at** (some activity).
> I need to improve my ability in (some activity).